# How do I create/display variables/values in java-script that reference an element or are within an element with a certain id

Tags: javascript

The title basically says it all.
How would I declare a variable with a certain element like article with the id of main.
Or display values within a span element with an id.
This is part of a homework project I'm working on and I can't seem to do it correctly, what am I doing wrong?

```
    // a. declare sourceNode referencing article element with id main
var sourceNode = document.getElementById("main");

// f. using innerHTML display values within span elements with id's
document.getElementById("totalNodes").innerHTML = nodeCount;
document.getElementById("elemNodes").innerHTML = elemCount;
document.getElementById("attNodes").innerHTML = attCount;
document.getElementById("textNodes").innerHTML = textCount;
document.getElementById("wsNodes").innerHTML = wsCount;
```

Here are the instructions im trying to base my answers off of:

[instruction 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4hAx.png)

> a. Declare the **sourceNode** variable referencing the `article` element with the id *main* in the current document

[instruction 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Esul.png)

> f. Using the `innerHTML` property, display the values of the *nodeCount, elemCount, attCount, textCount,* and *wsCount* variables within the `span` elements whose ids are *totalNodes, elemNodes, attNodes, textNodes,* and *wsNodes*, respectively.

Comment: Your title and question are equally confusing... personally, I have no idea what you're asking. Any chance you can give a more descriptive example or something?

Comment: I also do not understand what you're asking and furthermore I'm guessing that it's possible you don't understand the directions and information you were given for your homework? Which you aren't sharing with us.

Comment: I have edited adding in the instructions that I'm trying to figure out sorry for my poor wording @gforce301

Comment: From the instructions you've included, it looks like your code does exactly as you've been instructed to do (assuming the variables `nodeCount`, `elemCount`, etc, are declared)

Comment: They are declared earlier in the code alright thank you for the help both of you! @Santi